# Cauchy sequence are bounded -terence tao analysis exercise 5.1.1

Tags: real-analysis

Prove the cauchy sequence is bounded.
Hint- uae the fact that $a_n$ is eventually 1-steady and thus can be splited into a finite sequence and a 1-steady sequence. Then use the fact that every finite sequences are bounded.

How to split this into finite sequence as there are infinite number of finite sequence because the number of terms in cauchy sequence is infinite.

Comment: Here there is no special in using the number 1. Any number can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a fixed real number and $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a Cauchy Sequence. Because $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy Sequence, there is a $n_\epsilon \in \mathbb{N}$ with $|a_m-a_l|\leq \epsilon$ for all $m,l\geq n_\epsilon$. Define $a$ by $$a=\max_{n\leq n_\epsilon} a_n$$
Then we get for every $n\in \mathbb{N}$
$$a_n=a_n-a_{n_\epsilon}+a_{n_\epsilon}\leq \epsilon+a <\infty$$
and $a_n$ is bounded.

Answer (score 2):

There exists $N \in \Bbb N$, such that for all $n \ge N$ and all $p \ge N$, $|a_n - a_p | < 1$. Then, for each $n \ge N$, we have $|a_n| = |a_n - a_N + a_N| \le |a_n - a_N| + |a_N| < 1 + |a_N|$.

Now, consider the two sets:

$$\{a_1,...,a_{N-1}\}$$

$$\{a_n, n \ge N\}$$

Comment: Ahmed hussein     Could u please say how to conclude that $|a_i| \leq m$.       I mean which set contain the largest value. I mean how will u conclude the second set as a finite sequence.

Comment: @Saager: let $|a_k|$ be the largest one out of $|a_1|,...,|a_{N-1}|$, so that the first set is bounded above by $|a_k|$. Next, you know that the second set is bounded above by $1 + |a_N|$. Putting $M = \max(|a_k|, 1+ |a_N|)$, we get $|a_n| \le M$ for all $n \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: So, we do not need to worry about whether the largest value is in the first or second set; we simply take the maximum between the largest value in the first set and the upper bound on the second set.